# Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $a^2 = 3b^2$. Show that $0 < b < a < 2b$ and $(3b-a)^2 = 3(a-b)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

...Use these and the Well-Ordering Principle to prove that no such $a$ and $b$
exist.  From this it follows that $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}$

I have no idea where well-ordering principle comes in for this question?

Comment: Can you prove $0<b<a<2b$? What have you tried? Is it possible that $0<a<b$? Why not?

Comment: I've tried square rooting both sides and got a is sqr(3) times b, so b must be greater than 0 and smaller than a... a is equal to 1.732b so smaller than 2b. But I don't know where the Well-Ordering Principle

Answer (score 1):

fairly common to demand the $a^2 = 3 b^2 $   be the solution in positive integers that has the smallest possible value of $a+b$

But then they point out $(3b-a)^2 = 3 (a-b)^2 .$  You are required to show that $a-b, 3b-a$  are both positive integers, and then show that
$$  3b-a + a-b   < a+b,   $$
which is a contradiction of the assumption that $a+b$ was minimal

Answer (score 0):

Typical trick due to Hardy:

\begin{align}
  \sqrt{3} &= \frac{a}{b} \tag{assuming in lowest terms} \\
  \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}&= \frac{3b}{a} \\
  \sqrt{3} &= \frac{3b-a}{a-b}  \tag{Componendo et Dividendo}
\end{align}

Since $1<\sqrt{3}<2$,
$$b<a<2b \implies 0<\color{blue}{a-b}<\color{red}{b}$$

Now $\dfrac{3b-a}{\color{blue}{a-b}}$ is lower than $\dfrac{a}{\color{red}{b}}$, **contradiction**.

See similar trick on another post of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659296/prove-sqrt60-is-irrational/1659339#1659339).

Also papers [*here*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/8720-the-irrationality-of-2-3-5-6/C252481612AFB28468E8F230E17A06FC), [*here*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/abs/10223-a-visual-proof-that-is-irrational/6A28B90702AE39278A85D06CDA536892) and also [*here*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315207?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).