# Prove that if integers $a,b$ satisfy the equation $2a^2+a=3b^2+b$ then...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove that if integers $a,b$ satisfy the equation $2a^2+a=3b^2+b$ then numbers $a-b$ and $2a+2b+1$ are perfect squares. $a,b$ are integers . This is my  proof is it correct? I'm referring to one answer from this thread [$\sqrt a$ is either an integer or an irrational number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number) .
Proof for $a-b$.
$$a-b=3b^2-2a^2$$
Referred here: If $a^{1/b}=\frac{x}{y}$
 where $y$
 does not divide $x$
, then $a=(a^{1/b})^b=x^b/y^b$
 is not an integer (since $y^b$
 does not divide $x^b$
), giving a contradiction.
Lemma: If $y$
 does not divide $x
$
, then $y^b$
 does not divide $x^b$. There is also a proof of this lemma on the linked question.
It is straightforward to see that $a-b=3b^2-2a^2$ is an integer.
I don't have a proof yet for the second part.

Comment: What if $a^{1/b}$ is an irrational number?

Comment: Then it is of the form $\frac{x}{y}$ .

Comment: No, I said it could be an **ir**rational number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your proof works, because $a^{1/b}$ could be an irrational number, in which case it cannot be written as $\frac{x}{y}$ with $x,y$ being integers. Moreover, I'm not sure why you would be interested in the quantity $a^{1/b}$.

For a hint, note that
$$(a-b)(2a+2b+1)=2a^2-2b^2+a-b=b^2.$$
What is the greatest common divisor of $a-b$ and $2a+2b+1$? What can you conclude?

Comment: How do you want me to find GCD of $a-b$ and $2a+2b+1$ ?

Comment: Assume that a prime number $p$ divides both $a-b$ and $2a+2b+1$. What can you get?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Suppose $p$ divides $a-b$. From the equation $(a-b)(2a+2b+1)=b^2$, what other term must it divide?

Comment: I guess $b$ must be the GCD. Could you show me an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct for simple reasons: If it were correct, it would prove *too much*. To see this, note that it seems that your argument woiuld work just as fine if the equation were
$$ 2a^2+a = 11b^2+b$$
instead. But this equation holds for $a=3$, $b=1$ and $a-b=2$ is not a square.