# Show that $\sqrt{q}$ is irrational

Tags: proof-verification, radicals, alternative-proof, rationality-testing

> Let q be a positive integer such that $q \geq 2$ and such that for any
>   integers a and b, if $q|ab$, then $q|a$ or $q|b$. Show that $\sqrt{q}$
>   is irrational.

Proof;

Let assume $\sqrt{q}$ is a rational number, where $n \neq 0$ and $\gcd (m,n)=1$, meaning $\sqrt{q} = \frac{m}{n}   \Rightarrow q=\frac{m^2}{n^2} $

Since $n^2 \nmid m^2$, $q|m^2 \Rightarrow q|m$, so $m=qt$ where $t\in \mathbb{Z}$

By substitute $m=qt$ in the equation $qn^2 = m^2$, we get $n^2=qt^2$.

Since tells us that $q|n^2$ and $t^2|n^2$, it contradicts with the assumption $\gcd (m,n)=1$; therefore, $\sqrt{q}$ is irrational.

I get this proof with the assistant of the course, but is there any flaw or mistake? What are the other methods for proving this statement, can you at least give one different method? And how can I improve this proof?

Comment: What would it mean to "improve" the proof?

Comment: @AJY In the way that I wrote the proof.

Comment: What about $q=a=4$, $b=2$?

Comment: @jacer21, $q$ is explicitly assumed to be prime.

Comment: @Ennar, how so ?

Comment: @jacer21 Then $q \mid a$.

Comment: @AJY Which satisfies the condition that if $q |ab$, then $q | a$ or $q |b$

Comment: @jacer21 Right, how silly of me.

Comment: @Leth, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element). What we usually call prime positive integer is what in algebra is called [irreducible element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element). It's a consequence of [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) that prime and irreducible positive integers are one and the same thing.

Comment: @jacer21, but $4\mid 2\cdot 2$, and yet, $4\not\mid 2$. You are confusing existential and universal quantification.

Comment: @Ennar I basically understand nothing, Could you explain the case when q=4 ?

Comment: what about then a=b=4  also ?

Comment: @Leth, read my comment above. Basically, $(\forall a,b)\ q\mid ab\implies q\mid a$ or $q\mid b$ is equivalent to $q$ being prime number.

Comment: @Leth, it doesn't matter if $q = 4$ satisfies given implication *for some* $a,b$. It doesn't satisfy it *for all* $a,b$. For example, $a=b=2$.

Comment: If $q$ is not a prime then for some $a,b>1$ we have $q=a\cdot b$, but $a<q$ and $b<q$ since they are factors of $q$. So $q$ divides neither. Take contrapositive of this and your condition basically says $q$ is a prime

Comment: @Ennar, Firstly, the fact that q is prime explained with those theorems  is something that I haven't studied, so using this knowledge doesn't help me.Secondly, so you are saying that the statement is wrong ?

Comment: @Leth, this is completely irrelevant, the statement is true. I was just addressing jacer21 as he tried to make counterexample to the claim by using that $\sqrt 4$ is not irrational. This counterexample doesn't work since $q$ must be prime by explicit assumption, and $4$ is not prime. I've given you links since you asked me about it, but as I said, it is completely irrelevant for the proof you gave, which looks ok.

Comment: @Ennar My bad, you are correct. I misread

Comment: The tag ([tag:logic]) should be used for questions about [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic), see [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/logic/info).

Answer (score 2):

**Proof using [Bézout's Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezoutsIdentity.html)**

For $\sqrt{q}$ to be irrational, $q$ must not be a perfect square. Thus, we only concern us with non-perfect square $q$.

Assume that $\sqrt{q}$ is rational. Therefore $\sqrt{q} = \frac{m}{n}$ where $\gcd{(m, n)} = 1$.

By Bézout's Identity, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $mx + ny = 1$

Now $\sqrt{q} = \sqrt{q}(1) = \sqrt{q}(mx + ny) = (\sqrt{q}m)x + (\sqrt{q}n)y = qnx + my = \text{an integer}$

Which leads us to a contradiction, since we initially assumed that $q$ wasn't a perfect square. Hence, $\sqrt{q}$ is irrational.

Comment: I did not understand the part $(\sqrt{q}m)x + (\sqrt{q}n)y = qnx + my$

Comment: Notice that from our initial assumption we get $m = \sqrt{q} n$

Comment: @Leth See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/4585/242), which explains how to view such Bezout-based proofs as *descent* on denominators. See also many other proofs in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

We just have to show that for any prime number $p$, $\sqrt{p}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.
If we assume $\sqrt{p}=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ we get the identity $pb^2=a^2$.
For any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, let $\nu_p(n)=\max\{m\in\mathbb{N}: p^m\mid n\}$. The identity $pb^2=a^2$ implies
$$ \nu_p(pb^2) = \nu_p(a^2) $$
but that is impossible, since $\nu_p(a^2)$ is an even number and $\nu_p(pb^2)=1+\nu_p(b^2)$ is an odd number. $\sqrt{p}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ trivially follows.

Comment: why just the odd numbers ?

Comment: @Leth: I misread "*for any $q\color{red}{>}2$ such that $\ldots$*" in the main question, now fixed. It is not really relevant, indeed.

Comment: but I still don't understand why the p is prime.Above Ennar gave some info about it, but it is about something that I haven't studied.

Comment: @Leth: $$q\mid(ab)\implies q\mid a\text{ xor } q\mid b$$ is the very definition of *prime*. As an alternative, it is easy to show that only prime numbers (by your current definition) may have such property.

Comment: Can you prove it ? or give a reference ?

Comment: @Leth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element