# Show if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I proved by showing if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x^2 \not\in \mathbb{Z}$.

> Because $x = \frac{m}{n}$, at least one of $m$, $n$ is odd.
>   $\text{odd}^2 = \text{odd}$.
>   Therefore $x^2 = \frac{m^2}{n^2}$ is also rational.
>   Therefore $x^2$ is not integer.
>   Proved by contrapositive.

Is my proof correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a gap in your proof, because saying that $x^2=m^2/n^2$ is also rational, does not immediately imply that $x^2$ is not integer. You need to give a further argument here. The proof has been given often here on MSE, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number).