# Show that $ \sqrt{p}$ is irrational if $p$ is prime

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

> Show that $ \sqrt{p}$ is irrational if $p$ is prime.

I did the proof before that $ \sqrt{2}$ is irrational by contradiction:

Let's assume that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, therefore given $m$ and $n$ sharing no common factor:
$$\sqrt{2} = \frac{m}{n}$$
$$2=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$$
$$2n^2=m^2$$

As $2 \mid 2n^2$ , it follows that $2 \mid m^2$, and that $2\mid m$. 
Therefore $\exists k \in Z$ s.t. $m=2k$

Using back
$2n^2=m^2$ and substituting $m=2k$ in it, we have:
$$2n^2=(2k)^2$$
$$2n^2=4k^2$$
$$n^2=2k^2$$

Similarly, as $2 \mid 2k^2$, it follows that $2 \mid n^2$, and that $2 \mid n$.
Therefore, $\exists j \in Z$ s.t. $n=2j$

Finally, if $m=2k$ and $n=2j$ $n,j \in Z$, $m$ and $n$ share a common factor $2$. We have a contradiction with the assumption.

It follows that $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be rational but irrational.

This is where I am so far with my understanding. What would the best approach be with the original question?

What would be the approach be here? I was thinking to state that if $p$ is composite then $\exists x,y,m,n \in Z$, all four prime numbers, s.t. $p=xy$.and have then
$$\sqrt{xy}= \frac{m}{n}$$
but I don't see how I could move forward in this direction.

Much appreciated

Comment: A more general statement here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126586/for-which-natural-numbers-n-is-sqrt-n-irrational-how-would-you-prove-your/2126663#2126663

Comment: Why assume p is composite? If you are trying to do a proof by contradiction, there is nothing that will contradict.  Composite numbers may or may not have rational square roots and will tell you nothing about the roots a prime will have.  Also if p=xy x and y don't have to be prime there's no reason why m,n must be prime either.  That statement is simply wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just try the same thing? Assume $\sqrt{p} = \frac{m}{n}$ for coprime $m,n$. Then $p = m^2/n^2 \implies m^2 = pn^2$. Hence $p \mid m^2 \implies p \mid m$ by Euclid's Lemma. Then $p \mid n^2 \implies p \mid n$. Contradiction.

Comment: Sir contradiction to what? I think to "$m$ and $n$ are coprime" ? (Since they are coprime so they don't have divisor $>1$) am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

More is true:
If $n$ is not the square of an integer,
then
$\sqrt{n}$
is irrational.

Here is one of the many proofs:

[Follow-up Question: Proof of Irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391411/follow-up-question-proof-of-irrationality-of-sqrt3/1391466#1391466)