# Why don't textbooks foreground marginally generalized theorems?

Tags: education

1. 'Marginally generalized theorems' refers to [theorems](http://pirate.shu.edu/~kahlnath/Top100.html) that were generalized so marginally that they can still be taught, and understood by the students, in the same course.

#### Examples of theorems NOT marginally generalized:

2. A skilled high-schooler can understand [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series#Generalization), [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#Generalizations), and [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#Generalizations). But their generalizations are too cavernous.

#### Examples of theorems that can be marginally generalized:

3. Spivak proves $\sqrt{2}$'s irrationality fully, but banishes [$a^{\frac 1b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467/53259)'s to the exercises. Isn't proving (only) the latter more efficient?
4. Most multivariate calculus textbooks devote 1 chapter to Green's Theorem. Why not introduce Stokes's first, and then state Green's as a corollary?
5. Why not prove first [Gauss's generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Gauss's_generalization) of Wilson's Theorem:

$\forall \; p \; \text{odd prime}, \alpha \in \mathbb{N} : \quad \prod_{k = 1 \atop \gcd(k,m)=1}^{m} \!\!k \ \equiv
\begin{cases}
-1      \pmod{m}  & \text{if } m=4,\;p^\alpha,\;2p^\alpha \\
\;\;\,1 \pmod{m}  & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}?$

I refer not [the further generalization requiring group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784679/why-dont-textbooks-foreground-marginally-generalized-theorems?noredirect=1#comment5742546_2784679).

Comment: The last one: Because the generalized version requires the students to know what a group is, whereas Wilson's theorem is purely about modular arithmetic.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft +1. Thanks. I corrected my example.

Comment: This might be a pedagogical question rather than a mathematical one.

Comment: Suggestion: eg on 3 - because it is sometimes best to teach a method by using a concrete example which can be easily motivated/understood. Then abstract/generalise when you have a model to follow. And note also this generalises further via the rational root theorem.

Comment: Asked again at [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/14084/77).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment but a very standard proof of Stokes theorem in 3 dimensions is to reduce the problem and apply Green's theorem.