# Show that $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$ using infinite descent

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing, infinite-descent

Standard exercise is to show $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality)).  There are examples on Math.SE such as [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917983/the-proof-of-sqrt2-is-not-rational-number-via-fundamental-theorem-of-arithm?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263864/proof-that-sqrt5-is-irrational?rq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131391/proving-sqrt-3-is-irrational?noredirect=1&lq=1), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452078/prove-that-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-is-irrational)].

If we adjoin an element to $\mathbb{Q}$ does the same proof by contradiction work?  I'd like to show $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$ where $x = i$ is a solution to $x^2 + 1 = 0$.  Perhaps I could begin the same way.  We are solving:

$$  p^2 = 2 q^2 $$

where $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$.  We certainly have $2 = (1+i)(1-i)$ so that $2$ does factor in this new ring, but these two numbers are relatively prime.  We have:

$$ \sqrt{1 \pm i } \notin \mathbb{Q}(i)$$

And therefore, their product does not belong in that field as well.  Does that look correct?  Is has correct ideas, but I don't think the logic is presented correctly.

There are may solutions to this problem, so I've also indicated a certain line of proof I'm trying to follow, using [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Irrationality_of_%E2%88%9Ak_if_it_is_not_an_integer).  I'm asking, Does the descent argument we typically use over $\mathbb{Z}$ carries over to $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ ?

---

Alternatively, we can write any element of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ as $a + bi$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. If we have $(a+bi)^2 = 2$ Then $a^2 - b^2 = 2$ and  $2ab = 0$.  Then necessarily $b = 0$ and $a^2 = 2$.  This only uses descent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and we never use that $2$ factorizes into $(1+i) \times (1-i)$.

In contrast: [Proving $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q_7}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360282/proving-sqrt2-in-mathbbq-7)

Comment: Consider the field $\mathbb R$ which does not contain $\pm i$ but does contain $i\times -i$. So you have made an unjustified assumption in your proof.

Comment: perhaps I could argue that $1+i$ divides $p$ ?  And also $1-i$ and therefore again $2$ divides $p$.

Comment: I suppose you can use the same proof. Suppose $a + bi \in \Bbb Q(i)$ has the property that $(a + bi)^2 = 2$. Then $a^2 + 2abi - b^2 = 2$. Comparing the coefficients, it must be that $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, so either $a^2 = 2$ or $-b^2 = 2$. Now use the usual proof that this can't exist in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\sqrt2=a+ib\in\Bbb{Q}[i].$ Then $a^2+b^2=2$ and clearing denominators we can consider the Diophantine equation $p^2+q^2=2r^2.$ Since RHS is even both $p$ and $q$ has to be same parity. Moreover

$$\left(\dfrac{p-q}{2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{p+q}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2}=r^2.$$

Then using primitive Pythagorean triples we have $p=(m+n)^2-2n^2,$ $q=(m-n)^2-2n^2$ and $r=m^2+n^2$ for some $m,n\in\Bbb{Z}.$

If $p=0$ or $q=0,$ then we have a contradiction $\sqrt2\in\Bbb{Q}.$
Otherwise $b\neq 0,$ which is also contradiction as $\sqrt2\in\Bbb{R}.$

Comment: How do you get $a^2+b^2=2$ (by considering the magnitude?)

Comment: @DS: See the "square of the absolute value".

Comment: I know that. I wanted to know whether concluding this was valid.

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that $\mathbb Q(i)$ does not contain a root to $x^2+2=0$.

To do this ione possible route is to this we work in $\mathbb C$ and notice that $\mathbb Q(i)$ must contain $\{a+bi| a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$.

If we can show $\{a+bi| a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$ is a field then clearly we must have $\mathbb Q(i)=\{a+bi| a,b\in \mathbb Q\}$.

Clearly it is closed under addition,multiplication and additive inverses. Recall that $(a+bi)^{-1}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}$ which is also of the desired form.

Thus all we have to prove is that $(a+bi)^2\neq -2$ for $a,b\in \mathbb Q$.

Clearly $\sqrt{2}i$ and $-\sqrt{2}i$ are not of this form. (One can also prove that $(a+bi)^2=-2$ has no solution by hand)