# How to check this number $\sqrt{47}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Prove that $\sqrt{47}$ is irrational number.

I know that a rational number is written as $\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ & $q$ are co-prime numbers. But I do not have any idea to prove it irrational number.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Look at the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and emulate it.

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64643/how-to-prove-that-sqrt-3-is-an-irrational-number

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/is-this-proof-that-sqrt-2-is-irrational-correct

Comment: if we assume that $\sqrt{47}=\frac{p}{q}$  and $(p,q)=1$ what can you say about the equation $47\cdot q^2=p^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$47$ is a prime, hence you may just mimic the proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$. Let:

$$\nu_{47}(m) = \max\{n\in\mathbb{N}: 47^n\mid m\}.$$
Assuming $\sqrt{47}=\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, it follows that:
$$ p^2 = 47\, q^2 $$
but $\nu_{47}$ of the LHS is even while $\nu_{47}$ of the RHS is odd, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If $\dfrac p q =\sqrt{47}$ then $p^2=q^2\cdot 47$.  That means the number of $47$s in the prime factorization of $p^2$ is one more than the number of $47$s in the prime factorization of $q^2$.  But that cannot happen because $p^2$ and $q^2$, both being squares, must both have an even number of $47$s in their factorizations.

(This relies on the theorem that tells us that an integer cannot have more than one prime factorization.)