# Show that there is no rational number such that $x^2=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

i've juste asked myself if it is possible to proof that there is no rational number such that $x^2=3$ using rational sequence. I know that there is a more direct maneer to proof this assertion but i'd like to know if it is possible to show with sequences.
I was thinking to try to proof by absurd and show then that the left and right limit are not equal.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $\sqrt 3$ is an irrational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64643/how-to-prove-that-sqrt-3-is-an-irrational-number). See Aryabhata's proof using continued fractions.

Comment: I don't see how you want to define your sequences. Can you elaborate on that?