# How to prove $\sqrt3$ is irrational?

Tags: diophantine-equations, irrational-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that the square root of two is irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-you-prove-that-the-square-root-of-two-is-irrational)

How to prove $\sqrt3$ is irrational using Fermat's infinite descent method?

Like says in Carl Benjamim Boyer's book.

Isnt the same prove to $\sqrt2$, in Boyer's book says something like this.

$\sqrt3=a1/b1$

$1/(\sqrt3-1)=(\sqrt3+1)/2$

$\sqrt3=(3b1-a1)/(a1-b1)$

Comment: Quite similarly to this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-you-prove-that-the-square-root-of-two-is-irrational/16#16

Comment: Exactly the same way you prove it for $\sqrt{2}$: write $\sqrt{3}=\frac{a}{b}$, or $b\sqrt{3}=a$. Square both sides, conclude you can find $a'$, $b'$, $a'\lt a$, $b'\lt b$ with $\frac{a'}{b'} = \frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

Because the greatest power of $3$ that divides $p^2$ must be even, whereas the greatest power of $3$ that divides $3q^2$ must be odd. So $(p/q)^2$ can't equal $3$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a valid proof!

Comment: @CutieKrait: This is just a spite downvote, because I made somebody look foolish in another thread.