# Can a^2 = 2b^2 have a solution where a, b are in Z but not zero?

Tags: diophantine-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that the square root of two is irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-you-prove-that-the-square-root-of-two-is-irrational)

Can $a^2 = 2b^2$ have a solution where $a, b$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not zero?

$\mathbb{Z}$ = positive and negative whole numbers

Comment: If you can solve $a^2=2b^2$,  then $$2=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2$$ which means that the square root of $2$ is rational.  See the linked page for some proofs that this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If you take square root of the both sides you get:

$|a|=\sqrt{2} \cdot |b|$

So the LHS represents an integer while RHS represents an irrational number therefore equality isn't true so there is no solution of this equation in the set of integers without zero.