# Prove that $\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt{2}}$ is not a rational number

Tags: proof-verification, alternative-proof, radicals, nested-radicals, rationality-testing

> Prove that $\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt{2}}$ is not a rational number

**My attempt:**

Consider the polynomial $ (x^3-5)^2 - 2 = x^6 -10x^3 + 23 =  0 $.  By the rational root theorem, we can conclude that $ \pm 1$ and $ \pm 23 $ are the only possible rational solutions*.  Since none of those are solutions and $ \sqrt[3]{5 - \sqrt{2}} $ is, it follows that $ \sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt{2}} $ is not a rational number.

> Is this proof correct?  What are some other ways of proving this?

*The case of $\pm 1$ is trivial.  That of $\pm 23$ is not; I could factor out 23s to make it easy to do by hand.  $23^6 - 10*23^3 + 23 = 23(23^2(23^3-10)+1)$.  Since $23^3>10$, it follows that the function does equal $0$ for $23$.  $-23$ would be the same except that we would replace $-10$ with $+10$.

Comment: You want $(x^3-5)^2-2$ (according to the title).  Also, how do you know that $\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt{2}}$ isn't $2$, or any of these others?

Comment: The title was a typo, but we'll go with it because that's what people responded to. Edit: Ok i've modified my proof to fit the titular problem.

Comment: The case of $\pm 1$ is trivial.  That of $\pm 23$ is not; I could factor out 23s to make it easy to do by hand.  $23^6 - 10*23^3 + 23 = 23(23^2(23^3-10)+1)$.  Since $23^3>10$, it follows that the function does equal 0 for 23.  -23 would be the same except that we would replace -10 with +10.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\sqrt[3]{5-\sqrt2}=a$ where $a$ is rational

Cubing either sides, $\displaystyle5-\sqrt2=a^3\iff 5-a^3=\sqrt2$ which is [irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/is-this-proof-that-sqrt-2-is-irrational-correct) unlike the Left Hand Side

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $\ x^3\not\in \Bbb Q\Rightarrow x\not\in\Bbb Q,\,$ since $\,x\in \Bbb Q\Rightarrow x^3\in\Bbb Q$

Answer (score 0):

A simple, algebraic consideration: Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{(5-\sqrt2)}.$ Then $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ contains $\sqrt2,$ so $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]\gt1,$ i.e. $\alpha$ is irrational.
In essence this is nothing than the answer by Bill, but expressed more abstracly.