# Is the cubed root of x irrational if and only if x is irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Is the cubed root of x irrational if and only if x is irrational?
Hoping for simple answers.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try looking for some examples/counterexamples?

Edit: Is there any reason this is tagged "discrete-mathematics"?

Comment: Instead of editing to "Donotanswer $\times\infty$", once your question has been answered simply accept an answer from those given below to designate the question as "answered" so that your question can be helpful to other users in the future.  Editing out your question does not help future users.

Comment: are you asking because of lab rat?

Answer (score 4):

We have that whenever $x^3$ is irrational, $x$ is also irrational, but you don't have the converse:

For example, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational, but $2$ is rational.

Comment: $x^3$ irrational does not imply $x$ is rational, you have $\sqrt{2}^3=2\sqrt{2}$ and both irrational.

Comment: Sorry, it was a misstype, it was obviously x^3 irrationnal imply x **ir**rationnal

Comment: @Tryss, spelling nitpick: "rational" and "irrational" with one n each.

Comment: @HenningMakholm : I'm french, and in french the similar word has two n, so when I'm not carefull (like here), you can bet that I'll make this mistake :'(

Comment: Imagine myself, that the word in my language is "Irracional". Some years ago I used to write it like that in english.

Answer (score 2):

No. Most numbers' cube roots are irrational, including but not limited to 2, 3, 4, 5...

Answer (score 1):

This breaks down into two statements:

- $\sqrt[3]{x}\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow x\in\mathbb{Q}$
- $x\in\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{x}\in\mathbb{Q}$

The first statement is true, but the second isn't.  To see why the forward implication is true, suppose that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is rational, then it can be written as some $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\neq 0$.  Then $x=(\sqrt[3]{x})^3=(\frac{p}{q})^3=\frac{p^3}{q^3}$ is also written as a ratio of two integers (with $q^3\neq 0$) and is therefore rational.

For the reverse implication, you can prove that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is an irrational number using the same technique as proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.  (See for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162134/is-this-proof-that-sqrt-2-is-irrational-correct) or this [wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality)), giving an example of when $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ but $\sqrt[3]{x}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, showing that the reverse implication is false.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: $\sqrt[n]{a}$ for $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 2}$, if real, is either an integer or irrational.

Proof: If it's irrational, we're done. Otherwise $\sqrt[n]{a}=\frac{k}{l}$ for some coprime $k,l\in\Bbb Z$.

Then $al^n=k^n$. Then $l=1$, since if not, then $p\mid l\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid k^n$, by [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) $p\mid k$, so $\gcd(k,l)\ge p$, contradicts $\gcd(k,l)=1$. QED

So $\sqrt[3]{a}$ for an integer $a$, if not an integer, is always irrational. So $\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3}$, etc. are irrational.