# Prove: the equation $p^2=2$ is not satisfied by any rational $p$.

Tags: analysis

Rudin has gone through complex scenarios to prove this theorem, but isn't the following correct?

By contradiction, let $\exists p\in \mathbb{Q}; p^2=2$. Take $p=a/b$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(a,b)=1$. So, $a^2/b^2=2\Rightarrow a^2=2b^2\Rightarrow a=\sqrt{2}b$, yielding $\sqrt{2}b\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, contradicting $a\in \mathbb{Z}$. $\square$

Comment: This is not correct; if $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ then you have derived $a=\sqrt{2}b=pb\in \mathbb{Q}$, which is not a contradiction.

Comment: After you derive $a^2 = 2b^2$, can you apply [unique prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)? Also, who is Rudin and what complicated stuff did he do on this question?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, Walter Rudin, he wrote a few famous analysis textbooks. Specifically, he showed that sets of rationals where $p^2>2$ and $q^2<2$ have no greatest lower bound and no least upper bound (respectively) that belong to either set.

Comment: @vadim123 I think you comment is a fine *answer*! I think you should post it.

Comment: @vadim123 Absolutely! I need more concentration now.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-you-prove-that-the-square-root-of-two-is-irrational (I'm not saying this is a duplicate, because this newer question is mainly about critiquing a proposed proof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the correct way to prove this, anyway:

Let $p\in \mathbb{Q}$, so $\exists a,b\in \mathbb{Z}; p=a/b$  where *a* and *b* are not both even. Thus, $a^2=2b^2$, yielding $a^2$ is even, hence *a* is even, so *a* is divisible by 4. It follows that the $2b^2$ is divisible by 4. So $b^2$ is even implying *b* is even. That contradicts the assumption that not both *a* and *b* are even. $\square$

Answer (score 2):

You started assuming that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, as $b$ is rational and then $\sqrt{2}b$ is rational!