# Show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational using the integer root theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, proof-verification, roots, rationality-testing

> Show that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational using integer root theorem.

Let $P(x)=x^2-2$. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is a root of this polynomial, had it been a rational (suppose $\sqrt{2}=\frac{p}{q}$) no, by integer root theorem $q|1$. Hence $q=\pm1$. Moreover $p|-2$. So $p=\pm1$ or $p=\pm2$. Either way $\sqrt{2}=\pm1$ or $\pm2$ which is absurd.

Is it alright?

Comment: Alright, but slightly overdone I guess. The integer root theorem already says that the rational roots of $x^2-2$ are integers and divisors of $(-)2$.

Comment: Please avoid creating overly specific tags like "rational root theorem". Nobody is going to subscribe to that, or use it for filtering. I replaced it with the tags (polynomials) and (roots).

Comment: Here's the fifth post (fourth question) on this website: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5. One of its answers solves this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16596/

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917983/the-proof-of-sqrt2-is-not-rational-number-via-fundamental-theorem-of-arithm

Answer (score 1):

"Absurd" is not quite enough.

You should say that if $q=\pm1$ and $p=\pm1$ or $p=\pm2$ then $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2=1$ or $4$.  But $\sqrt{2} ^2=2$, so $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be written as $\frac{p}{q}$.