# Is $\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt[3]{15}}$ rational or irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, radicals, rationality-testing

Is $\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt[3]{15}}$ rational or irrational? Prove it.

I am having a hard time with this question. So far what I did was say, assume it's rational, then $$\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt[3]{15}}=\frac{x}{y} \Rightarrow \sqrt{7}y=x\sqrt[3]{15}$$
I then showed the product of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational so the expression above is irrational on the left and right side. I can't get to a contradiction to prove it's irrational so I'm currently thinking it is rational but I don't know how to go about proving it.

Comment: Take the $6^{\textrm{th}}$ power of each side and then argue as in [standard proofs that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-you-prove-that-the-square-root-of-two-is-irrational).

Comment: We can assume $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime. Take the sixth power. We have $7^3 y^6=15^2x^6$. Argue that $7$ divides $x$ and therefore $7$ divides $y$ contradiction. Or argue that $3$ divides $y$ and therefore $x$.

Comment: So it is irrational? I just want to be sure I'm right. It contradicts the unique factorization into primes so it must be irrational, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factoring $\,7^{\,\large \color{}{3}} y^{\large 6}\!=15^{\large 2}x^{\large\color{}{6}}$ into primes, $\,7\,$ has odd power $\,3\!+\!6j\,$ on LHS, but even $\,6k\,$ on RHS

Comment: **Note** that the argument depends crucially on both the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, i.e. the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.*

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the number is rational, let
$$ \frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt[3]{15}} = \frac{x}{y} $$
where $\gcd(x, y) = 1$, then 
$$ \sqrt{7}y = \sqrt[3]{15} x \implies 7^3 y^6 = 225 x^6 $$
So 
$$ 7^3  | x^6     $$
which implies $ 7| x $.

Let $x = 7m, \; m \in \mathbb N$. Then we have 
$$  7^3 y^6 = 225 \times 7^6 m^6 $$
which means 
$$  y^6 = 225 \times 7^3 m^6 $$
once again we have 
$$ 7^3  | y^6     $$
which implies $ 7| y $. And this is contradictory to the coprimality between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is rational then so is $x^3$, and hence so is $\frac{15}{7}x^3$.

Applying this to
$$x=\frac{\sqrt7}{\root3\of{15}}$$
shows that if $x$ is rational then so is $\sqrt7$.  But I expect you already know that this is not the case.  Therefore $x$ is irrational.

(If you are not allowed to assume that $\sqrt7$ is irrational, it is pretty easy to prove.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: This is the sixth root of $\dfrac{343}{225}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:$7^3y^6 = 15^2x^6 \Rightarrow \left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^6 = r \Rightarrow t^6 - r = 0 \Rightarrow pt^6 - q = 0$. Use Eisenstein's criteria.