# Very simple proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, real-numbers, rationality-testing

I came across a nice-looking proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational [here](https://numberwarrior.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/insanely-simple-proof-of-irrationality-of-sqrtn-when-n-is-not-a-perfect-square/). It somehow seems to good to be true. What are the assumptions being made in the proof and if this proof is indeed correct, why is not as popular as the [classic proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_Root_of_2_is_Irrational/Classic_Proof)? Is the latter burdened with more trivial assumptions? I've always found that part about $p$ and $q$ being in lowest terms slightly lacking in rigor.

Comment: This 'new' proof also suggests a fraction in lowest terms.

Comment: It seems fine. Maybe it is not as popular because it is more general. Regarding the lowest term rigor, its rigor is usually skipped over when learning the proof. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent

Comment: What is unrigorous about "lowest terms"?  - it is equivalent to the assertion that the highest common factor of numerator and denominator is $1$.

Comment: Here is a proof by Fermat. Suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Then the right-angled triangle with sides $(1,1,\sqrt{2})$ has rational sides length and area $1$. Hence $1$ is a congruent number, i.e., $x^4+y^4=z^4$ has a nontrivial integral solution. Contradiction.

Comment: It's not unrigorous, but it does rely on facts about factorization of integers.  Specifically, that rationals can be reduced to lowest terms, such that if $B/A$ is in lowest terms and $B/A = b/a$, then there is an integer $c$ such that $b=cB$ and $a=cA$.  It's true, but it has to be proved.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Nice, adding to the archive. (Although showing from the integer axioms up that $x^4 + y^4 = z^4$ has no solutions is probably more demanding that the standard proof! ;-) )

Comment: @SimonS yes, of course. This is not  a "very simple proof", but a nice one.

Comment: I find it just a complicated way to say that if $\sqrt{N}=A/B$, then $N=\sqrt{A^2}{B^2}$.

Comment: I remember the sense of "unrigor" that the op hints at. It seems that we declare the fraction to be in lowest terms, and then our contradiction that we arrive at is precisely a contradiction of that declaration that we didn't need to make. What's subtly missing in this line of thought is that although we didn't need to make that declaration, it is done without a loss of generality.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/4491/242) for a more conceptual presentation, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16544/242) for another form using fractional parts.

Comment: Here is another short proof that I don't quite remember the origin of. If $a/b = \sqrt{2}$ then $a^2 = 2b^2$, which is impossible, as the parity of the power of 2 in the prime factorization of both sides is different.

Comment: Of course, "unique prime factorization" is another thing more advanced than the usual proof based on "even/odd".

Comment: @GEdgar But said proof doesn't require Existence & Uniqueness of prime factorizations; rather it needs only E & U of factorizations of the form $\,2^k n,\,$ for $\,n\,$ odd, which is much more elementary.